# newman econnrefused when running collection

Tags: postman, newman

i have created a Collection in Postman. it is composed of GETs and it is testing if the response is 200. When i run it in Postman, all of the test passes. but when i run in newman using the collection link (command: newman run "collectionname.postman_collection.json"), i get the error:

> unable to fetch data from url "collection link". connect ECONNREFUSED

am i missing a setting or something? i dont have any authentication on my collection.

i exported the test and tried to run it locally but is still fails. this is what it looks like for one of the test.

> Get http://linktoapi [401 Unauthorized, 1.4kb, 0ms] **Response is 200** (the bolded text is colored red in the results

i hope im not confusing you guys. i need to run the collection in newman so i could integrate it in Jenkins but these errors are baffling me.

i appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact command, I'll have to guess ... You might try adding the -k parameter.  This is for 'Disable strict ssl'.  You can see a list of all of the command line parameters in this post: 
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman